# javascript rollover image - (how) can I set css styles for onmouseover image?

Tags: javascript, css, onmouseover

newbie here so pls be patient :)

I have an image (Image#1) which is aligned against the far left of the page (all body padding and margins set to 0) and have added some rollover javascript so a new image (Image#2) appears in its place on mouseover.
Image#2 is larger than Image#1.

At the moment, on mouseover Image#2 appears but is not aligning far left against the page (the default page margins seem to have been re-introduced and body CSS rules ignored).

Is there anyway of applying an ID to Image#2 so I can control the CSS styles for it? Or any other way of removing the margin which appears on mouseover? Basically I would like the 2 images to overlap at the far left corner.

Help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some code?  The margins shouldn't change.  It almost sounds like Image #2 has margins built into it.

Comment: @Amy - how can I paste the code properly? sorry - new to this, like I say :)

Comment: If you could create a sample of what you're talking about on jsbin.com, that would be even better. You can copy / paste your html / css / javascript in there.

Comment: @DavidN I updated that link so that it swaps images people can see - http://jsbin.com/ujomu5/3/edit  I cannot replicate the issue you're describing (I'm using Chrome). I do not see any additional padding being added into the page on the image swap.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

$('img#id').mouseover(function(){
$(this).css("property","value");

});
```

it requires jQuery..

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
var elem = document.getElementById("id"); //your img id is passed in here
elem.onmouseover= function(){
this.style.yourPropertiesInCamelCase = "value";
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
P.S.: You can google camelCase if you don't know what it is...
Be careful with css properties in "pure" Javascript. There are possible browser inconsistencies... Your code can become not crossbrowser...

Comment: Thanks @DrStrangeLove. I am not familiar with JQuery so wouldn't know how to combine the above with the JS and HTMl I already have. Do you know of any good tutorials I could look at that might explain above in more detail? Or could you perhaps expand on above? Thanks

Comment: it's quite easy... add  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js to script src between head tags. it will enable jQuery code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way this can be done without JQuery though? Ultimately all I am trying to do is ensure that the CSS styles applying to the body tag still function onrollover. (I am really new to all this and only started using JS for the first time today so would rather leave JQuery until I am more familiar with JS. If possible?!) Thanks again for your help

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to do a bit more learning to understand properly and get this right though to be honest. Here's a link to what I have at the moment. I don't understand why you can't have the body CSS styles apply to the mouseover image though?? http://jsbin.com/ujomu5/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Did you concider...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage() {
   document.getElementById("theImg").src = "other.gif";
}
</script>

<img src="/myImage.gif" id="theImg" onmouseover="changeImage()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a  with fixed dimensions and 0-paddings and add the images inside it. It might work? Not sure.

Anyway, to do roll-over, you need to change the "src" attribute of the initial image. The rest should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the anchor hover state in CSS to swap out a background image instead of using javascript for something so simple. Also you should make the images one image so that you can load them at one time and just change the background position on hover...

http://jsfiddle.net/k36am/